# Accidentally changed website url

Tags: admin, site-url

Hello i accidentally changed my wordpress url and now cannot access admin. can anyone tell me how to fix this please? i don't have access to c-panel either.

I tried adding this to wp-config.php via ftp

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.org/folder' );
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://www.example.org/folder' );

still does not work

Answer (score 1):

So you do not know the url what you changed? If so, then follow these steps

1. Go to the phpmyadmin
2. go to the options table
3. search for this option_name siteurl
4. then you can know what you changed then using that url you can login
5. then change it back

Comment: i know the url but it doesn't work either. can you tell me how to access phpmyadmin please? i don't think i can, because the website was created by someone else. i have only ftp access.

Comment: If you have hosting access then you can easily access to your databases and phpmyadmin